# Drivers for selenium will not work 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Very new to this, and I cannot get chromedriver or geckodriver to work. They are both located in `/usr/local/bin/`. So I know they are in PATH.

My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')  
driver.get('http://www.google.com/xhtml');
```

Here what I get back:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "11.py", line 3, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('Desktop/chromedriver')  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 68, in __init__
    self.service.start()   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 81, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message) selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

Comment: If your code is `webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')`, why does the error message say `webdriver.Chrome('Desktop/chromedriver')`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the absolute path of the `ChromeDriver` along with the **`Attribute Key`** as follows :

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')  
driver.get('http://www.google.com');
```